# Creating a View that dynamicaly populates a temporary column with variable substring data from the description column

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2008-r2, dynamic-programming

My skills in SQL are beginner to intermediate at best so I am checking here for any help with this project I need to do.  I am not asking for you to give me the code I need but any assistance to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

I am using SQL Server 2008 r2 and need to create a view.  The view will be of the table tblDataHistory.  That table consist of 5 columns (only need 3 of those in the view).

They are as follows.

```
-HistoryEventID (autonumber) - not needed
-ExecutionID (int) - Needed
-EventTypeID (int) - not needed
-Timestamp (datetime) - needed
-Description (varchar(max)) - needed
```

The view needs to only keep those 3 columns ExecutionID, Timestamp, & Description.  It will need one more column and this is where I am lost a bit on the execution.  I need to look for some key word phrases inside the Description column and if it exists in that row populate the 4th column with that phrase.

Phrases I am looking for are as follows

```
-"Conversations"
-"Error"
-"Failed"
-"On Behalf Of"
-"Acted Upon"
-"Approve"
-"Delete"
-"Route"
-"Reject"
-"Release"
-"Duplicate"
-"Restart"
-"Send"
-"Submit"
-"Comment"
-"Conversation"
-"Attach"
-"Redaction"
-"Matched"
-"Return to Start"
-"Print"
-"Started"
-"Ended"
-"Saved"
-"Backfill"
-"Reassign"
-"Note"
-"Action Button"
-"Priority"
-"Completed"
```

Basically I need the last column to be created and populated with those key phrases depending on if the Description column contains that phrase.

This seems like it should be really easy to do but I don't seem to find any simple solution anywhere that I can apply to my situation.  Any suggestions on where to start?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working with some coworkers we came up with a solution to our problem.  First of all there were too many keywords that we "didnt care about" so we thinned down the list.  Even then we could have kept the list as is and just made this script longer.  Created a view and in the select statement that populates the view we used case statements and wildcards to find the blocks of characters that we were looking for and had those populate additional columns based on the data in the description.  Here is that Select Statement

```
SELECT HistoryEventID, ExecutionID, EventTypeID, Timestamp, Description, 
                  CASE WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Invoice Approval started%' THEN 'STARTED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%acted upon the document with the command%' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Submit.%' THEN 'SUBMITTED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%on behalf of%' AND [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%clicked the action button %' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Submit%' THEN 'SUBMITTED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%acted upon the document with the command%' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Send to AP.%' THEN 'SENDTOAP' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%on behalf of%' AND [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%clicked the action button %' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Send to AP.%' THEN 'SENDTOAP' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%acted upon the document with the command%' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Release to GP.%' THEN 'RELEASED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%on behalf of%' AND [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%clicked the action button %' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Release to GP.%' THEN 'RELEASED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%acted upon the document with the command%' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Reject.%' THEN 'REJECTED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%on behalf of%' AND [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%clicked the action button %' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Reject%' THEN 'REJECTED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%acted upon the document with the command%' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Route.%' THEN 'ROUTED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%on behalf of%' AND [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%clicked the action button %' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Route%' THEN 'ROUTED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%acted upon the document with the command%' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Approve.%' THEN 'APPROVED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%on behalf of%' AND [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%clicked the action button %' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%APPROVE%' THEN 'APPROVED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%acted upon the document with the command%' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Restart Workflow.%' THEN 'RESTARTED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%on behalf of%' AND [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%clicked the action button %' AND 
                  [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Restart%' THEN 'RESTARTED' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE 'Invoice Approval ended.%' THEN 'ENDED' ELSE '' END AS TYPE, 
                  CASE WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Invoice Approval started%' THEN 'SYSTEM' WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%Invoice Approval ended%' THEN 'SYSTEM' WHEN [DESCRIPTION]
                   LIKE '%(symetra\%' THEN SUBSTRING(Description, (CHARINDEX('symetra\', Description)) + 8, 6) ELSE '' END AS [USER], 
                  CASE WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%on behalf of%' THEN 'YES' ELSE '' END AS IMPERSONATED, 
                  CASE WHEN [DESCRIPTION] LIKE '%on behalf of%' THEN SUBSTRING(Description, (CHARINDEX('symetra\', Description, CHARINDEX('on behalf of', Description))) + 8, 6) 
                  ELSE '' END AS IMPERSONATED_USERID
FROM     Data_HistoryEvents
```

I am sure this could have been done more elegantly but this worked and so we went with it.

Answer (score 1):

First create a table of your keywords, maybe as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE keyphrases (keyPhrase VARCHAR(100))
INSERT keyphrases VALUES ('Conversations')
INSERT keyphrases VALUES ('Error')
INSERT keyphrases VALUES ('Failed')
INSERT keyphrases VALUES ('On Behalf Of')...etc
```

Then in your VIEW, left join the new table to your query with the LIKE operator:

```
SELECT
  DH.ExecutionID,
  DH.Timestamp,
  DH.Description,
  K.keyPhrase AS MatchedKeyPhrase
FROM
  tblDataHistory DH 
  LEFT JOIN keyphrases K ON DH.[Description] LIKE '%' + K.keyPhrase + '%'
```

If you only want to include matched rows then change the LEFT JOIN to just JOIN.

Beware,these are expensive types of joins. Use them wisely. Keep the key phrases table as short as possible.